# Creating a patterned array in linear time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, stack, time-complexity, pseudocode

> Given an integer array P[1..n], we want to build an array S[1..n]:
>
> Among the members in P[1..i-1] that are larger than P[i], we choose P[k] with the largest index (1<=k< i <=n). S[i] will hold the value of P[k]. If there are no numbers greater than P[i] in P[1..i-1] we place 0 in S[i].

Obviously, the first element in S[] will be 0, as there are no elements before it. The others can be found using iteration through the array P[], however, that will take `O(n^2)`, as it is the sum of the series `1+2+...+n=[1/2n(n+1)]`.

Is there a way to do this in linear time? I have thought about using *stacks*, as it will help with pulling the highest index with a larger value, however, any way I try to implement it still requires me to go through the created stack, so it is actually worse - time to create the stack, and time to pop out until reaching the desired element, all over again and again. Perhaps there's another way?

Any ideas/suggestions/hints on how it could be done?

**Examples:**

```
P[5,4,9,7,8]-->S[0,5,0,9,9]
P[1,5,2,3]-->S[0,0,5,5]
```

**Clarification:**

We should assign to S[i] the highest **indexed** number, still greater than P[i] in P[1..i-1]. For example, assume P[8,2,1]. While 8 is the greatest value, S[3] will hold the value 2, as it is the highest indexed number still greater than P[3]. -->S[0,8,2].

**Edit:**

I believe I have an O(n) solution, using a stack. the idea in pseudocode:

```
BuildS(P[])
    Temp-StackNIL
    for(i<--1 up to n)
        while(Temp-Stack≠NIL)
            if(P[i]<=top[Temp-Stack])
                pop(Temp-Stack) //goes back to while
            else
                S[i]<--top[Temp-Stack]
                push(Temp-Stack,P[i]) //goes back to for
        S[i]<--0 //out of while
        push(Temp-Stack,P[i]) //goes back to for
```

Am I having it right?

Comment: @user3386109 Isn't in this case the previous that is tackled ? does not look like a dupe to me.

Comment: I have looked through the other question before - I will edit my question to clarify further why it is not duplicate. @user3386109

Comment: The only difference between this and the other question is that you start at the ***end*** of the array at iterate to the beginning.

Comment: I see, that was on oversight on my behalf indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is an O(n) solution, although I came up with O(n log n).

Suppose we have a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (BST). Main loop pseudocode:

```py
for i in [0, len(P)):
    S[i] = BST.search(P[i])    
    BST.insert(P[i], i)
```

I assume that `search` returns `S[i]` for `P[i]`.

```py
def search(value):

    def getSbyIndex(index):
        return index == -inf ? 0 : P[index]

    curVertex = BST.root
    maxIndex = -inf
    while:
        if curVertex.value > value:
            if !(curVertex.leftChild exists):
                return getSbyIndex(maxIndex)
            else:
                maxIndex = max(maxIndex, curVertex.index, curVertex.rightChild.subtreeMaxIndex)
                if curVertex.leftChild.value <= value:
                    return getSbyIndex(maxIndex)
                else:
                    curVertex = curVertex.leftChild
        else:
            if !(curVertex.rightChild exists):
                return getSbyIndex(maxIndex)
            else:
                curVertex = curVertex.rightChild
```

I wrote `search` unoptimized (*and also did not check some nonexistent vertices cases for the sake of simplicity, be careful!*) on purpose to give you the general idea. We start from the root of BST and go down by usual rules updating `maxIndex` when it is needed (see explanation below). Each leaf of our BST (which actually represents some P[x]) contains 5 fields:

- leftChild
- rightChild
- value (that P[x])
- index (x)
- subtreeMaxIndex (maximum of .index among vertices of a subtree with the current vertex as a root)

So when is it needed? Let's say we have `curVertex.value <= value`. It means we have to go to the right subtree. Any `vertex.value` of the left subtree is also `<= value`, so there are no vertices (`P[y]`) in the left subtree and in the current vertex that fulfill the `P[y] > P[new]` condition, therefore we do not change `maxIndex`.

Similarly, let's pretend we have `curVertex.value > value`, which leads us to the left subtree. But this time any `vertex.value` of the right subtree is `vertex.value > value`, so all `P[y]` among the current and the right subtree vertices are actually greater than `P[new]`, so we have to find their maximal index, which equals to max(curVertex.index, curVertex.rightChild.subtreeMaxIndex), and try to update `maxIndex` with it.

The last thing we need is `insert`.

```py
def insert(value, index):
    newVertex = BST.insertNode(value)
    newVertex.index = index
    curVertex = newVertex
    while curVertex is not BST.root:
        curVertex.subtreeMaxIndex = max(curVertex.index, curVertex.leftChild.subtreeMaxIndex, curVertex.rightChild.subtreeMaxIndex)
        curVertex = curVertex.parent
```

Here I did not check for children existence again, and also added `parent` field. `BST.insertNode` is just a basic BST inserting method, which returns us a new vertex object. After that we just go upwards to the root, updating `.subtreeMaxIndex` for every vertex on the path.

Overall, we have `n` iterations of the main loop and `log n` for both `insert` and `search` calls, so the final complexity is O(n log n).

Comment: That's already a great improvement, I will wait to see if anyone can come up with a O(n) idea, still.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a solution in `O(n)`

The idea is to keep track of the highest value encountered while looping through `P` and compare `P[i]` to this value.

Here is the pseudocode I came up with (using your first example)

```
P = [1,5,2,3]
S = []
highest = 0

for i in P
    if highest < P[i]
        highest = P[i]
        S[i] = 0
    else
        S[i] = highest
```

I assumed here that you used only values >= 0 but if you got negative values `highest` should be initialized with the minimum value possible.

Comment: Interesting, but this will, if I understand it correctly, always assign the highest value greater than the one we are comparing it to. The question requires to assign the highest **indexed** number, which holds greater value than the one we are comparing it to. Or am I getting your code wrong?

Comment: No you are right indeed, I'll try to look for an answer taking into account indices based on the same idea.

Comment: I haven't found a `O(n)` way to solve this problem with my base idea, you should consider accepting dubov94's answer. Also if someone downvotes this I'll be able to delete this answer (right ?)